# if it rains 75% of days, i take a sample of n=30 days, what is the probability of rain for 20+ days

Tags: probability, self-study

I have found the z score by taking the square root of pqr (30)*.5*.5 =sq rt of 7.5.  z score = 1.15 and using tables probability = 23.27% chance of rain more than 20 of the 30 days we checked.  Is this correct?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?  It seems to be buried in the title, which is so telegraphic as to be almost incomprehensible.

Comment: sorry, my teacher asks if it rains 75% of the days in seattle and she takes a sample of n=30, what is the probability that it will rain for more than 20 of those days?

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that.  It's quite a bit different than my original interpretation! In the meantime, you will find a large number of very similar questions asked and answered here: include "binomial" in your search of our site.

Comment: ok. i think i get the probability part, but the 75% is throwing me off.  i assume that is an important part of the problem

Comment: A focused search for related questions on this site [turns up several hundred posts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+probability+self-study+-conditional+-approximate).  Many are closed because they are poorly phrased, but one of the first hits that is not is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6619/probability-of-getting-between.  It is the same as your question  but with the numbers changed.  The method shown in the answer works with your question too.  If you're interested in using a Normal approximation, then include "Normal" within your search terms.

Comment: is it (30/21)*(.5)^21*(.5)^9?  and then do the same formula with 22-30 (replacing 21) and then add up all the answers?